# How do I deal with out of bounds for Conway's Game of Life?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, conways-game-of-life

Currently working on a class project trying to recreate Conway's Game of Life. Here's a copy of my code, my main issue is with my runRound() method. I have to go through and check to see how many neighbors each cell has that are alive(true) or dead(false) and edit my new grid accordingly. However I keep going out of bounds when trying to check around the edges of my grid and tried to implement code to avoid that but I must be missing something. Thank for any advice! still kind of new to this!

```
package Programs;

public class GameOfLife {
private boolean[][] grid;
private int time;

public GameOfLife() {
    grid = new boolean[10][10];
    time = 0;
}

public GameOfLife(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 1) {
        row = 10;
    }
    if (col < 1) {
        col = 10;
    }
    grid = new boolean[row][col];
    time = 0;
}

public boolean[][] getGrid() {
    boolean[][] newGrid = new boolean[grid.length][grid[1].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            newGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    return newGrid;
}

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void simpleSetUp(int[][] array) {
    if (getTime() == 0) {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            if (array[0].length == 2) {
                if (array[row][0] >= 0 && array[row][1] >= 0 && array[row][0] <= grid[0].length
                        && array[row][1] <= grid[0].length) {

                    grid[array[row][0]][array[row][1]] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public void clearGrid() {
    this.time = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; row < grid[col].length; col++) {
            grid[row][col] = false;
        }
    }

}

public void runRound() {
    time++;
    int live;
    boolean[][] newGrid = getGrid();

    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[col].length; col++) {
            live = 0;
            if (row - 1 >= 0 || col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col - 1] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row + 1 < grid.length || col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col + 1] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row - 1 >= 0 || col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col + 1] == true ){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row + 1 < grid.length || col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col - 1] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row + 1 < grid.length) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row][col + 1] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row][col - 1] == true){
                    live++;
                }
            }

            if (grid[row][col] == true && live == 2 || live == 3) {
                newGrid[row][col] = true;
            } else {
                newGrid[row][col] = false;
            }

        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[col].length; col++) {
            live = 0;
            if (row - 1 >= 0 || col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col - 1] == false){
                live++;
                }
            }

            if (row + 1 < grid.length || col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col + 1] == false){
                live++;
                }
            }
            if (row - 1 >= 0 || col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col + 1] == false){
                live++;
                }
            }
            if (row + 1 < grid.length || col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col - 1] == false ){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row + 1 < grid.length) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col] == false ){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (row - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col] == false){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (col + 1 < grid[col].length) {
                if(grid[row][col + 1] == false){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (col - 1 >= 0) {
                if(grid[row][col - 1] == false){
                    live++;
                }
            }
            if (live == 3) {
                newGrid[row][col] = true;
            } else {
                newGrid[row][col] = false;
            }

        }

    }

}

public void runGame(int foo) {
    for (int poo = 0; poo < foo; poo++) {
        runRound();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looking at `if (row - 1 >= 0 || col - 1 >= 0)`, what if `row` is `1`, and `col` is `0`?  Do you really want to execute `if(grid[row - 1][col - 1] == false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that your bounds checks are "or" logic: you go ahead with the computation if *either* **row** or **col** is in bounds.  You need to have them **both** in bounds; use an **and**.

If you're tired of that, you can get a similar effect by padding your entire grid with **false** values, one layer on each side.  Your actual cells are in the range 1 through grid.length+1; row/col 0 and grid.length+2 are **false**.